# Create Facebook test page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a test page on Facebook while developing an app. Per the [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages), I've created a test user, noted the user id and created an access token.

I'm now trying to make a POST request via curl to [create a page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/#Creating)

```
curl -i -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/{user-id}/accounts?category_enum=MARKETING_AGENCY&name=Test%20Page&access_token={access-token}
```

However the response is an error

> (#100) The parameter name is required

Seems I have supplied the `name` parameter though; any ideas?

**EDIT**

If I remove the `category_enum` param, the error becomes

> (#283) Requires manage_pages permission to manage the object

However, I have verified the user has the `manage_pages` permission....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the facebook api documentation... On the surface it looks like only the name parameter is required, however after hours of experimentation with the Graph API Explorer I managed to create the test page with no less than 9 required parameters!

Comment: Which is actually mentioned in the docs: Other requirements vary depending on the type of page you are creating but may require the following parameters: name, about, picture, and cover_photo.